# Can MySQL create tables within tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to organize the accounts for an app into a "hierarchical" grid system.

i.e. Super_Grid_A has grids 1, 2, 3 in it and Grid 1 has accounts A, B, C in it, Grid 2 has accounts B, C, D in it, etc.

Any pointers?

Comment: Read about relational databases, how you can connect data from different tables. There's no such thing as a table within table, but you can use IDs to reference items across different tables.

Comment: I don't think you want to do that, Mysql will break. Maybe look into JOIN tables

Comment: Nested tables are not supported in MySQL, however they are a concept that exist in [ORACLE databases](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm). http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,60008,161545#msg-161545 indicated mySQL does not support them, but multi valued attributes are.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create tables within tables in MySQL. But you can use a master/slave approach for your grid table. Something that will look like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbb8/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE grid
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(12), `master_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO grid
    (`id`, `name`, `master_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Super_Grid_A', 0),
    (2, 'Grid 1', 1),
    (3, 'Grid 2', 1),
    (4, 'Grid 3', 1)
;

CREATE TABLE account
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO account
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'account A'),
    (2, 'account B'),
    (3, 'account C'),
    (4, 'account D')
;

CREATE TABLE grid_account
    (`grid_id` int, `acct_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO grid_account
    (`grid_id`, `acct_id`)
VALUES
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select master.name master_grid, slave.name slave_grid, acct.name account
from grid master
inner join grid slave on master.id = slave.master_id
inner join grid_account grid_acct on slave.id = grid_acct.grid_id
inner join account acct on grid_acct.acct_id = acct.id
where master.master_id = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbb8/1/0)**:

```
|  MASTER_GRID | SLAVE_GRID |   ACCOUNT |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 1 | account A |
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 1 | account B |
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 1 | account C |
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 2 | account B |
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 2 | account C |
| Super_Grid_A |     Grid 2 | account D |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of the way that MySQL works incorrectly. You should read up on a topic called "Relational Database Normalization": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

The reason I say this is because you state that Grid 1 will have ABC, and Grid 2 will have BCD, which means there will be overlap between Grid 1 & 2 on BC. Is that correct?

What you will most likely end up doing (If I understand your question correctly) is create a set of tables that relate to one another.

If you only have the 3 levels, then you will only need 3 tables. If you have ***n*** amount of tables, then you will need a more clever solution where perhaps the rows relate back to a relation table that points to keys in a psuedo circular fashion

Example of 3 level deep approach:

```
  Super_Grid                        Grid                       SubGrid
+-----+------+              +-----+-------+-----+             +-----+------+-----+
| key | grid |              | key | super | grid|             | key | grid | sub |
+------------+ key to super +-----+-------+-----+ key to grid +-----+------+-----+
|  1  |   A  | <-1-------n-<|  1  |   1   |  1  |<-1-------n-<|  1  |  1   |  A  |
+-----+------+              |  2  |   1   |  2  |             |  2  |  1   |  B  |
                            +-----+-------+-----+             |  3  |  1   |  C  |
                                                              |  3  |  2   |  D  |
                                                              +-----+------+-----+
```

Perhaps you might want to look into a no SQL approach. Something like MongoDB, because that will let you build a heirachical state a lot easier than building tables. It all depends on what your end goal is.